# Update AWS Lambda Alias to latest version aws_cdk

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

How can I publish new version of Lambda and update existing alias of a latest version using python aws-cdk. Current code below. This code give error 'alias already exists'. Additionally, the version doesn't always gets published (even though there's some change in the lambda function).

```
version = aws_lambda.Version(self, 'UpdateLambdaVersion', lambda_=existing_lambda_function)
alias = aws_lambda.Alias.from_alias_attributes(self, "alias", alias_name=existing_alias_name,alias_version=version)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this doc page for `currentVersion`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda-readme.html#versions

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.Function.html#currentversion

Setting the Alias version to fn.currentVersion should resolve the issue.

Comment: currentversion isn't available for me when I do existing_lambda_function = aws_lambda.Function.from_function_arn(...)

Comment: The error is : AttributeError: '_FunctionBaseProxy' object has no attribute 'current_version'. Did you mean: 'latest_version'?